# Include do arquivo .h não está sendo suficiente para criar instanciar uma classe

Tags: c++

Criei uma classe chamada Tabuleiro, faço os protótipos no arquivo **Tabuleiro.h** e mantenho o código no **Tabuleiro.cpp**, durante o estudo vi que apenas adicionando o **Tabuleiro.h** ao **index.cpp** já seria possível instanciar a Classe tabuleiro (new Tabuleiro(10,20,1)). Entretendo no meu código ele acusa erro, e só funciona se eu incluir diretamente o arquivo **Tabuleiro.cpp**.

Erro:

```
[Running] cd "c:\xampp\htdocs\grimoriec++\" && g++ index.cpp -o index && "c:\xampp\htdocs\grimoriec++\"index
C:\Users\kauen\AppData\Local\Temp\cchnmOmm.o:index.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `Tabuleiro::Tabuleiro(int, int, int)'
C:\Users\kauen\AppData\Local\Temp\cchnmOmm.o:index.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `Tabuleiro::to_string()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Quero saber se a maneira correta de se adicionar uma classe proveniente de um outro arquivo é pelo **arquivo.cpp** ou pelo **arquivo.h**, e caso seja a segunda opção o que eu tenho que mudar no meu código para que o include funcione ?

index.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "Tabuleiro.h"
using namespace std;


Tabuleiro::Tabuleiro(int x,int y,int z){
    this->tam_x = x;
    this->tam_y = y;
    this->tam_z = z; 
};

void Tabuleiro::to_string(){
   cout << this->tam_x << endl;
}
```

Tabuleiro.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Tabuleiro.h"
using namespace std;

Tabuleiro::Tabuleiro(int x,int y,int z){
    this->tam_x = x;
    this->tam_y = y;
    this->tam_z = z; 
};

void Tabuleiro::to_string(){
    cout << this->tam_x << endl;
}
```

Tabuleiro.h

```
#ifndef TABULEIRO_H
#define TABULEIRO_H

class Tabuleiro{
    public:
        int tam_x;
        int tam_y;
        int tam_z;
        Tabuleiro(int x,int y,int z);
        void to_string();
};

#endif // TABULEIRO_H
```

Comment: Na compilação você deve incluir todos os .cpp: 
g++ index.cpp Tabuleiro.cpp -o index

Comment: Agradeço muito. Funcionou agora estou pesquisando os comandos para compilar todos os CPPs de uma pasta